# How to plot jqplot chart inside phonegap app for Android

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, jqplot

I am developing a Phonegap App for Android.
I want to  implement a simple jqplot chart

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('graphcontentview', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
```

where graphcontentview is the id of the div that contains the chart.

When I run this code it produces the following error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'jqplot' at file:///android_asset/www/hellophonegap.js:27
```

where hellophonegap.js is my js file where I'll write the code later using this js into my index.html file.

I have added the following js code for jqplot chart

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jqplot.jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not getting what is the exact problem

Comment: What do you mean with "where hellophonegap.js is my js file where I'll write the code later using this js into my index.html file."?

Comment: I mean i m importing this js file into index.html file

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of jquery.jqplot.min.js file