# Jqplot error on PhoneGap for Android

Tags: android, cordova, jqplot

When trying to use jqplot in my Android PhoneGap application I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'jqplot' at file:
```

The graph is supposed to show after pressing a button.

I have exactly the same code running properly on a webpage in Chrome, which shows that the code is correct.

The link below has the same problem but nobody has answered it, so I thought i'd see if anyone has since found a work around.

[How to plot jqplot chart inside phonegap app for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280770/how-to-plot-jqplot-chart-inside-phonegap-app-for-android/14791954#14791954)

Includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>     
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js"></script>
```

jqplot code:

```
function makegraph() {
    $.jqplot('chartdiv',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

put data-ajax="false" in the href tag to force a page reload and the jqplot script will be loaded.

Otherwise put the jqplot script and css files after the data-role="page" tag and the script will be loaded each page transition.